# Optimization : conditional test on several matrices & extraction in R

Tags: r

I have a matrix

```
mat_a <- matrix(data = c( c(rep(1,3), rep(2,3), rep(3,3))
  , rep(seq(1,300,100), 3)
  , runif(15, 0, 1))
, ncol=3)

      [,1] [,2]      [,3]
 [1,]    1    1 0.8393401
 [2,]    1  101 0.5486805
 [3,]    1  201 0.4449259
 [4,]    2    1 0.3949137
 [5,]    2  101 0.4002575
 [6,]    2  201 0.3288861
 [7,]    3    1 0.7865035
 [8,]    3  101 0.2581155
 [9,]    3  201 0.8987769
```

that I compare to another matrix with higher dimensions

```
mat_b <- matrix(data = c(
  c(rep(1,3), rep(2,3), rep(3,3), rep(4,3))
  , rep(seq(1,300,100), 4)
  , rep(3:5, 4))
, ncol = 3)
      [,1] [,2] [,3]
 [1,]    1    1    3
 [2,]    1  101    4
 [3,]    1  201    5
 [4,]    2    1    3
 [5,]    2  101    4
 [6,]    2  201    5
 [7,]    3    1    3
 [8,]    3  101    4
 [9,]    3  201    5
[10,]    4    1    3
[11,]    4  101    4
[12,]    4  201    5
```

I need to extract the lines of `mat_a` where columns #2 of both matrices match. For those matches, both columns 1 also have to match. Also, column 3 of `mat_b` must be higher or equal to 4.
I cannot find any solution based on vectorization. I only came out with a loop-based solution.

```
output <- NULL
for (i in 1:nrow(mat_a)) {
  if (mat_a[i,2] %in% mat_b[,2][mat_b[,3] >= 4]) { 
    rows <- which( mat_b[,2] %in% mat_a[i,2]) 
    row <- which(mat_b[,1][rows] == mat_a[i,1])
    if (mat_b[,3][rows[row]] >= 4) {
        output <- rbind(output, mat_a[i,])
    }
  } 
}
```

This works but is extremely slow. It took less than one hour to run. `mat_a` has 9 col with 40,000 rows (could go higher), `mat_b` has 5 col and around 1.2 millions rows.
Any idea?

Comment: What does match means? Should the values in both columns be equal? You code seems to suggest that `element1 %in%  element2` is a match? And going by what you're asking for, I think `&` operator is missing in `if` statement.

Comment: By "match", I meant the values has to be equal, as you suggested.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is better to work with data frames when comparing tables as you are. That will use R's structures to their strengths instead of working against them. We use a simple merge to match the correct values. Then subset `b` with the necessary condition, `b$V3 >= 4`. On the end, `[-4]` lets the output more closely match your desired output:

```
a <- as.data.frame(mat_a)
b <- as.data.frame(mat_b)
merge(a,b[b$V3 >= 4,], by=c("V1","V2"))[-4]
#   V1  V2      V3.x
# 1  1 101 0.1118960
# 2  1 201 0.1543351
# 3  2 101 0.3950491
# 4  2 201 0.5688684
# 5  3 201 0.4749941
```